# pkg-config installed but not found

Tags: windows, haskell, gtk, msys2, pkg-config

I am trying to install Gtk for Haskell in Windows and getting following error:

```
C:\Users\abcd>cabal install haskell-gi
Warning: The install command is a part of the legacy v1 style of cabal usage.

Please switch to using either the new project style and the new-install
command or the legacy v1-install alias as new-style projects will become the
default in the next version of cabal-install. Please file a bug if you cannot
replicate a working v1- use case with the new-style commands.

For more information, see: https://wiki.haskell.org/Cabal/NewBuild

Resolving dependencies...
Configuring haskell-gi-base-0.23.0...
cabal: The program 'pkg-config' version >=0.9.0 is required but it could not
be found.

Failed to install haskell-gi-base-0.23.0
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
haskell-gi-0.23.0-1JHtHU5x2lkFiOcPtWhSw4 depends on haskell-gi-0.23.0 which
failed to install.
haskell-gi-base-0.23.0-6DTOa44NYLKIXS94FQX9lI failed during the configure
step. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1
```

However, I have already installed (and reinstalled) pkg-config using Msys2:

```
$ pacman -S pkg-config
warning: pkg-config-0.29.2-1 is up to date -- reinstalling
resolving dependencies...
looking for conflicting packages...

Packages (1) pkg-config-0.29.2-1

Total Installed Size:  0.54 MiB
Net Upgrade Size:      0.00 MiB

:: Proceed with installation? [Y/n]
(1/1) checking keys in keyring                                                                                                     [###############################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking package integrity                                                                                                   [###############################################################################] 100%
(1/1) loading package files                                                                                                        [###############################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking for file conflicts                                                                                                  [###############################################################################] 100%
(1/1) checking available disk space                                                                                                [###############################################################################] 100%
:: Processing package changes...
(1/1) reinstalling pkg-config                                                                                                      [###############################################################################] 100%
```

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you running `cabal` in an environment where it can find `pkg-config`? The [`haskell-gi` installation guide for Windows](https://github.com/haskell-gi/haskell-gi/wiki/Using-haskell-gi-in-Windows) recommends changing the `PATH` so `pkg-config` can be found.

Comment: Ok. I will try these steps and give feedback.

Comment: Also, are you *sure* you want to `cabal v1-install haskell-gi`? `v1-install` is *broken*, and doing this means you open yourself up to the possibility of horrendous version conflicts.

Comment: So, I should use `new-install` command?